# Publish Hexo drafts without being listed as Posts

Tags: javascript, node.js, hexo

I'm using Hexo as Static Site Generator and I want to process `_drafts` to `public` folder but without being listed as post.

I want to `name.md` draft go to `public/drafts/name.html` so I can show that draft published but not listed.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? hide them on the index page? You have to edit the theme that you use. Which one is it?

Comment: Yep something like that. But I thought there is a way to do that on the fly...
I'm using Hueman...
You can see it [here](http://lucaskatayama.com)

It's related to this [issue](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/1545)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no "hexo way" to this. Perhaps someone can code this and suggest a pull request to [issue you pointed out](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/1545).